# Clean solution to "cast" ObservableList<Foo> to List<IFoo>?

Tags: java, generics, javafx, interface, casting

My application has a simple plugin API. It's packaged in a separate JAR that plugin developers can use. Core app implements interfaces contained in API and exposes them to plugins loaded with [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Consider this code:

```
public interface ILayer {}

public class Layer implements ILayer {
    public void internalMethod() { /*snip*/ }
}

public interface IPlotter {
    List<ILayer> getLayers();
}

public class Plotter implements IPlotter {
    private ObservableList<Layer> layers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Layer> getLayers() {  // incompatible returned type
        return layers;
    }
}
```

My requirements are:

- Internally, `ObservableList` of `Layer`s is available
- API exposes only a `List` of `ILayer`s

Unfortunately, casting `ObservableList<Layer>` to `List<ILayer>` is illegal.

Returning `List<Layer>` in API would expose `internalMethod()` of `Layer`, so it's no good.

I could also have `private ObservableList<ILayer> layers`, then actually store `Layer`s inside, but that would require casting its items every time I use `internalMethod()` and I'm not very enthusiastic about this idea.

Is there a clean solution for this problem?

Comment: you could get over the cast error with `return (List<ILayer>)(List<?>)layers;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to change the signature of your interface method to allow returning a subtype of ILayer:

```
interface IPlotter {
    List<? extends ILayer> getLayers();
}

class Plotter implements IPlotter {
    private ObservableList<Layer> layers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public List<? extends ILayer> getLayers() {
        return layers;
    }
}
```

The main drawback is that somebody calling `List<? extends ILayer> layers = plotter.getLayers();` won't be able to add to the list: `layers.add(someLayer);` will not compile. This may or may not be an issue.

Comment: That's a good idea, but it doesn't solve my problem completely. I'll still have to cast when calling `getLayers()` in other core app classes.

Comment: You could add a package private `ObservableList<Layer> getLayersNoCast()` or something like that...

Comment: @gronostaj: But then you again leak `Layer` to other core classes, don't you?

Comment: @user140547, that's what I want to achieve. Core app can do whatever it wishes to, API exposes limited interface.

Comment: Well then you can create an internal method which is used by the core app, and create a new List<ILayer>, which is returned by `getLayers()`. The question remaining is how to keep those two lists in sync (and if the API provides such methods).

Answer (score 2):

@assylias's answer presents the cleanest solution available to the question.  The fact is that a `List<Layer>` without question *is not* a `List<ILayer>` (consider: you can add an `ILayer` that is not a `Layer` only to the latter), and Java does not accept casts that it recognizes can never be correct.

If you definitely want to return exactly a `List<ILayer>`, however, then you have at least three good alternatives:

1. Create a `List<ILayer>` in the first place, and live with the requisite casting inside `Plotter.getLayers()`.  Inasmuch as you (very reasonably) prefer not to cast, you can also
2. Use `List<Layer>` internally, and then create a *new* `List<Ilayer>` to return from the method, for instance

   ```
   return new ArrayList<ILayer>(layers);
   ```
3. As a variation on (2), you can create a wrapper list instead of a copy, supposing that it's ok for the returned list to be unmodifiable:

   ```
   return Collections.<ILayer>unmodifiableList(layers);
   ```

   Note the use of an explicit type parameter to give you the desired parameterization of the result type.  Note also, however, that this alternative places even more restrictions on use of the return value than does assylias's `List<? extends ILayer>` approach.

Comment: Oh, now it seems obvious why such casting is illegal. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Another soltuion might be to use the [bindContent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent-java.util.List-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) utility method:

```
public class Plotter implements IPlotter {
    private final ObservableList<Layer> layers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final List<ILayer> ilayers = new ArrayList<>;

    public Plotter(){
        Bindings.bindContent(ilayers , layers);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ILayer> getLayers() { 
        return ilayers;
    }
}
```

It has also the drawback that you shouldn't manipulate the List returned by getLayers. From the Javadoc:

> Once a List is bound to an ObservableList, the List must not be
>   changed directly anymore. Doing so would lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move `internalMethod` to `ILayer` if applicable. Or remove it if possible. If neither of these is possible, you could try to make `IPlotter` generic. Then, however a `IPlotter<Layer>` is another type as `IPlotter<Layer2>`.

```
interface ILayer {
}

class Layer implements ILayer {
    public void internalMethod() { /*snip*/ }
}

class Layer2 implements ILayer {
    public void internalMethod() { /*snip*/ }
}

interface IPlotter<T extends ILayer> {
    List<T> getLayers();
}

class Plotter implements IPlotter<Layer> {
    private ObservableList<Layer> layers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Layer> getLayers() {  // incompatible returned type
        return layers;
    }
} 
class Plotter2 implements IPlotter<Layer2> {
    private ObservableList<Layer2> layers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Layer2> getLayers() {  // incompatible returned type
        return layers;
    }
}
```

If you have multiple Plotters for different Layers you would have to use a

```
List<IPlotter<? extends ILayer>> i  = Arrays.asList(new Plotter(), new Plotter2());
```

Comment: The whole point of `internalMethod()` is to have an *internal* method that's not available through API. I need an `ObservableList` of `Layer`s internally and `List` of `ILayer`s externally, and both of these must always be in sync.

Comment: Well I guess then you can either use `List<? extends ILayer>` as suggested by others or maintain two lists if `ObservableList` provides functionality to keep them in sync, since a List can't have both the types `ILayer`and `Layer` at once.

Answer (score -1):

What about 
`private ObservableList<? extends ILayer> layers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` ?

Comment: The OP would still have to cast to call internalMethod.